# serial_data received event won't fire without break point

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, uart

I have a program that receives data through uart and process the data to binary file. I need to process the data in a separate thread due to timing requirements. I am trying to implement multithreading/ task but I believe I am not doing in the right way. I have separate classes: serial port and form1. I queue the data received in a queue of lists , each list is a packet of bytes received through uart.

The following code shows my serial port class

```
 public class FPGAPORT
{   
    int i = 0;
    List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
    public SerialPort PORT;
    Queue<string> num_elements = new Queue<string>();
    public ConcurrentQueue<List<byte>> msg = new ConcurrentQueue<List<byte>>() ;
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token1;


    public FPGAPORT(string PortName, int BaudRate)
    {
        PORT = new SerialPort(PortName, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        PORT.DiscardNull = false;
        DataCollectionTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DataCollectionTimer_Tick);
        DataCollectionTimer.Interval = 5000;
        DataCollectionTimer.Enabled = false;

    }

  private void DataCollectionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              //logic for queuing the lists(packets of bytes) 
                    if (queuing of one packet is done)
                    {
                        msg.Enqueue(data);
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1).Data_collection(), token1, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
                    }
     }
```

This is my form1 class

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {  
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

public void Data_collection()
        {

            if (FpgaDevice.msg.Count > 0)
            {
                List<byte> dequedData;
                {
                    if (FpgaDevice.msg.TryDequeue(out dequedData))
                    {
                        crc(dequedData);
                    }
                } 
                   //logic for saving data into binary file

            }
          else{
               // close port
              }

        }

        public void crc(List<byte> data_packet)
    {

       //logic for calculating CRC on the list dequeued(one packet of 
       bytes)
    }
  }
```

This code works but it is so slow and I believe it is because of the timer. I have tried using the serial data received event as in this:

```
 PORT.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;

    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, 
     SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
 //logic for queuing the lists(packets of bytes) 
                        if (queuing of one packet is done)
                        {
                            msg.Enqueue(data); 
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1).Data_collection(), token1, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
                        }
         }
```

However, it will never fire unless I have a breaking point on it from start. Using a timer was the only way to force the serial data received thread to execute.The CRC logic is long so probably whatever thread it is using, is hogging the computer. I am honestly clueless on how to fix it. It is my first multithreading project. I would really appreciate it if you could help or atleast point me in the right direction or perhaps refer some links. I wrote my computer specs below incase it was affecting the multithreading speed or something.

I am using a computer with the following specs:
**RAM:**  8GB Dual Channel DDR3 1600MHz (4GBx2)
**CPU:**  3rd Gen Intel Core i5-3570 Pro cessor (6MB, 3.4GHz) w/HD2500 Graphics, Dell Optiplex 7010.  This is a Quad-Core processor.
**HDD:** 2.5 inch 500GB Solid State Hyb rid Drive, Optiplex MT Desktop

Comment: I'm pretty sure the break point issue is just a side effect of something totally different. But from your code, it's not possible to tell what is going wrong. Start with an empty event handler (that only logs to console) to see if the serial port connection works correctly.

Comment: there is no issue with the serial port because when I remove task.factory.startnew, the serial received runs well but the program is very slow and thats why I tried to implement multithreading. So you think I should look at another wrong part other than the multithreading ? Maybe there is more efficient way to implement multithreading? Thanks for your help

Comment: It is difficult to fully understand what you are trying to do here - but multithreading may be the way to go. It is very common that data collection is done on one thread & processing of the data is done on another. If the application is slow then that may be down to the processing you do on the data rather than single/multi-threading. Is it possible that you are creating multiple tasks once you have a complete packet queued - that could slow things down. Maybe consider a separate thread that is monitoring the queue length & dequeuing & processing as packets become available.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to constantly check if the packet is available? I can only think of a timer that constantly checks if the packet.count>0.

Comment: The event is firing properly if you hit the break point.  The results are not going where you are expecting the results to go.  It look like you are creating a new form for each receive message.  When you step through code after getting to break point is anything displayed?  I suspect that you aren't seeing results because the new form is getting disposed after the data is displayed so you do not see the results when running code without break point.

Comment: @jdweng I am actually seeing results when I step through my code. Are you saying that (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1) generates a new form every time? Do you know a better method?

Comment: The instance of the form is "this".  You do not need a new instance.  If you get a cross-threaded issue then you need to use Invoke.

Comment: Yes, I got issues when I tried to call the method from form1. Form1.Data_collection() couldn't be called because it is not static

Comment: How can I call the method in form1 without creating new instance everytime?